# How view file get the variable from controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm a student and new to PHP. After searching a lot i still don't understand how the view file got the variable from controller.
I got the function view() from *Controller.php* class.

```
public function view($view, $data=[])
    {
        require_once "./mvc/views/".$view.".php";
    }
```

And i got a *HomeController.php* Extends the *Controller*

```
function toTheView($x,$y){
        $model = $this->model("User");
        $sum = $model->Sum($x,$y);
        $this->view("calc", compact('sum'));
    }
```

This is inn my *calc.php* view file.

```
<h3><?php echo $data["sum"]; ?></h3>
```

As you can see that the *calc.php* doesn't require any file from *Controller.php* or *HomeController.php* but how it's still can show that variable out? My IDE show the red alert on that line in *calc.php* but its still working.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @jrswgtr my problem is how the calc.php view file can have the variable that the controller passed in without any require or include :| How can it receive that variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `require_once` includes content of file in that place, so your *view fiel* can access any variables in same scope, so it can use passed variables from `public function view($view, $data=[])` and also access `$this`.

In the end your code looks like this:

```php
public function view($view, $data=[])
    {
        // after executing: require_once "./mvc/views/".$view.".php";
       <h3><?php echo $data["sum"]; ?></h3>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass all variables from your controller to view by using
[`get_defined_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) as array
and convert it into variables using [`extract`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract)

Example:
*HomeController.php*

```
    function toTheView($x,$y){
            $model = $this->model("User");
            $sum = $model->Sum($x,$y);
            $this->view("calc", get_defined_vars());
        }
```

*view() from Controller.php class*

```
    public function view($view, $data=[])
        {
            extract($data);
            require_once "./mvc/views/".$view.".php";
        }
```

*calc.php*

```
<h3><?php echo $sum; ?></h3>
```